# How is `initrd` for debian installer being built?

Tags: compiling, debian-installer

I would like to know how I could generate a custom `initrd` ([like the one here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/)) for the installer.

I've googled for how to do it and all I could find was basically how to insert a random kernel module or a preseed. That's **not** what I'm after here (I know how to unpack it, play around and then pack it again).

It's not just for the purpose of doing simple customizations I'd like to know.

It's out of curiosity (somehow canonical must have generated these without having to repack an existing initrd), the possibility to do modifications to the `initrd` in a sane way (fx alter it to log to RS232, adding support for other suites than main/restricted/universe/multiverse for both `.deb`s and `.udeb`s, to investigate the workings and non-working of the installer), the possibility to generate customized `initrd`s for different releases in a sane way. Possibly also eventually roll an `initrd` containing something else than the installer (fx some server software).

Comment: what you want to customise ?

Answer (score 0):

The initrd for the debian installer is a normal root file system, stripped down to the components required for the installer (i.e. using `udeb` packages that do not contain documentation).

Regular system boot uses a minimal initrd that loads a few modules, and then switches to the real root file system, but from the point of view of the kernel, the system is already running at this point, and the switch is entirely optional.

The installer runs from a ramdisk, which is initialized with the contents of the initrd archive. The only requirement the kernel has is that there is a file called `init` either in the root or below `sbin`, and this file will be invoked.

You can, for example, create a full installation using `debootstrap`, create an archive of that using `cpio`, and use that as an initrd -- so the process used by the kernel package to generate a small initrd is really a special case.

Comment: I suspect that the `initrd` of the installer is just a bunch of `.udeb`s, but what I'd like is first to know where I can find out which `.udeb`s that need to be assembled to get the `initrd` (and possibly how it's done).

Comment: Have you looked at the [d-I documentation](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/doc/internals/ch01.html), specifically chapter 4?